# MYSQL: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 can't figure out

Tags: mysql

I'm stumped have been playing with it for awhile, I've set everything but the primary key to allow nulls, I've tried removing some fields, but nothing works.

```
call Create_Login('Username', 'Passkey', 'Key', 1, 1, 1);
```

Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1   0.078 sec

```
CREATE DEFINER=`testdb`@`%` PROCEDURE `Create_Login`(
_Username varchar(15),
_Password varbinary(160),
_Salt varbinary(110),
_priviledge tinyint(3),
_WorkerID int,
_empID int
)
BEGIN

Insert INTO Login
Values (_Username, _Password, _Salt, _WorkerID, _priviledge, Curdate(), CURDATE(), 
_empID);


END
```

any help would be greatly appreciated also i've tried quoting and unquoting everything nothings worked so far. 6 input values, 6 supplied

Edit: I should add I've tried different values and such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem come from your `INSERT` query. Maybe there are one or several missing columns in your `INSERT`. BTW It is highly recommended to specify the column names in the `INSERT`

For instance:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Comment: no clue how specifying the coloumn names helped but it works now... also Username was my primary ID, figure if the manager wants someone to have multiple accounts it's fine you know.. 

Thank you greatly

Comment: you can specify the column names by specifying them just after the table name table_name (column1, column2, column3,...). The order should be the same as specified in the VALUES

Comment: I know that and I've found the problem above it's just that it goes based in column order which all I thought were present so didn't need to specify but apparently there was a stray one. Anyways I think I'll specify for now on thanks to this and your advice

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem out apparently when I clicked a row in my table the thing made an extra column. That's why specifying the values worked. Touchy DB...